# Displaying an image in Vue.js using Django REST

Tags: sql-server, django, vue.js, axios

I saved an image from user forms to mssql as binary data, now I want to display the image in user profile. I am working in Vuejs, Django and MSSQL. But there seems to be a problem with the URL as the image is not displaying. Backend is working fine, but there is an issue with Frontend

When the image is fetched using GET method, it displays a pic icon, but image is not displayed because it says there is an issue with the URL, any ideas how to solve this

*** UPDATE :
the invalid URL error no longer displays but the image still won't show with no error.
I updated the code by adding:
In Vue Comp:
imgElement.src= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(studentPicUrl);

In apiservice.js:
const imageBlob = new Blob([response_pic.data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

In MSSQL, image is set as data type "image"
this is my code:

```
views.py:

class studentPictures(APIView):
    def get(self, request, cnic, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            stdpics = StudentPictures.objects.filter(std_cnic=cnic).first()

            # Serialize the StudentPictures instance
            serializer = StudentPicturesSerializer(stdpics)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except StudentPictures.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Student Pictures not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        
    def put(self, request, cnic, *args, **kwargs):
        print("put called", cnic)
        stdpics_data = StudentPictures.objects.filter(std_cnic=cnic).first()

        if stdpics_data is not None:
            image = request.FILES['image']
            file_content = image.read()
            stdpics_data.image= file_content

            serializer = StudentPicturesSerializer(instance=stdpics_data,data= request.data,partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response({"res": "Object does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

models.py:

class StudentPictures(models.Model):
    std_pic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    std_cnic = models.ForeignKey(Student, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='std_cnic')
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'student_pictures'


apiservice.js:

 try {
      const response_pic = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/studentpic/${cnic}`, {
        responseType: 'blob',  // Specify responseType as 'blob'
      });

      // Check if the response contains image data
      if (response_pic.data) {
        // Convert the binary data to a Blob object
        const imageBlob = new Blob([response_pic.data]);

        // Create a URL for the Blob
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);

        // Store the URL in session storage
        sessionStorage.setItem('student_pic_url', imageUrl);
        alert(imageUrl)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching student picture data:', error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the calling function
    }

Im displaying the image using an id that is set in mounted as :

 mounted() {
    // Check if the session storage exists
    const studentPicUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('student_pic_url');
console.log(studentPicUrl);
    // Set the src attribute of the img element
    const imgElement = document.getElementById('studentImage');
    if (studentPicUrl) {
      // If session storage exists, set the src to the session storage
      imgElement.src = studentPicUrl;
      console.log("image is present");
    } else {
      // If session storage does not exist, set the src to the default image URL
      const defaultImageUrl = require('@/assets/img/default.jpeg'); // Adjust the path accordingly
      imgElement.src = defaultImageUrl;
      console.log("no image");
    }
  }
```

Comment: May be you can add *mime types* as options while creating the Blob `new Blob([data], { type: 'image/png' })`; and while setting the value inside **mounted() hook** try by adding `"data:image/png;base64," + studentPicUrl`

Comment: im gett ing a jpeg fom user so should I use image/jpeg or does that not concern here? also do i pass this "data:image/png;base64," + studentPicUrl  in  imgElement.src = studentPicUrl;  ?